# sending objects into database's and API's javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am trying to take the values of a form, turn them into an Object, then display said object at the bottom of the page. I eventually want to learn to send and access from API's. But I want to see my object appear first.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="submitF" class="formClass" >


    <input id="inp1" type="text" /></br></br>

    <input id="inp2" type="text"/></br></br>

    <input id="inp3" type="text"/> </br></br>

    <input id="inp4" type="text" /> </br></br>

    <input id="inp5" type="text"/></br></br>

      <button id="btn" type="submit" OnClick=button() > Submit </button>
</form>

<script>
var myObject = new Object(); {
inp1 = document.getElementById('inp1');
inp2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
inp3 = document.getElementById('inp3');
inp4 = document.getElementById('inp4');
inp5 = document.getElementById('inp5');
}


var button = function(myObject){

for(var i = 0; i < apartment.length; i++ ){
console.log(myObject(i));
}

};

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried to `display object at the bottom of the page` and `access API`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your syntax for creating the object is wrong, you don't need `new Object();`, and your use of the object-literal syntax after the `;` means the expression will be ignored. Change it to this:

   ```
   var myObject = {
       inp1 = ...
   };
   ```
2. `document.getElementById( id )` returns a `HTMLElement` object, not the value contained within, you will want to use the `.value` property:

   ```
   inp1 = document.getElementById('inp1').value
   ```
3. Don't use a semicolon when defining an object-literal, use a comma:

   ```
   inp1 = document.getElementById('inp1').value,
   inp2 = document.getElementById('inp2').value,
   inp3 = document.getElementById('inp3').value
   ```
4. Avoid `onclick` (either as a property or the `onclick=""` attribute). Instead use the `addEventListener` DOM method:

   ```
   var button = document.getElementById("btn");
   button.addEventListener( 'click', function(e) {

       alert("you clicked the button.")
   } );
   ```
5. Your code references an object named `apartment` which does not exist. I assume you mean `myObject`, but you're iterating over integer indexes, which don't exist as `myObject` is not an `array` but an `object` (arrays have indexed values, objects have named properties).

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in depth. I am new (as you can tell). I got it to log on the console beautifully! Now is there any advice you could give to help with sending the objects to be stored in an API?

Comment: @cwa I cannot, because you haven't told us anything about the API (a web-service, I presume) you're wanting to use. There are many types: e.g. SOAP, XML-RPC, WebSockets, and REST, etc - and different request/response types (XML, JSON, Form key/value pairs, etc) - to say nothing about authentication techniques (HTTP Basic, something custom, cookies, HMAC, OAuth, etc).

Comment: Okay i was debating on using the google parse server, or Mysql on Godaddy. Do you have opinions on either?

Answer (score 0):

change button type from submit to button, and change script as following:

```
<form id="submitF" class="formClass" >
    <input id="inp1" type="text" />

    <input id="inp2" type="text"/>

    <input id="inp3" type="text"/>

    <input id="inp4" type="text" />

    <input id="inp5" type="text"/>

    <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="button()"> Submit </button>
</form>

<script>
    var button = function(){
      var myObject = {
        inp1: document.getElementById('inp1').value,
        inp2: document.getElementById('inp2').value,
        inp3: document.getElementById('inp3').value,
        inp4: document.getElementById('inp4').value,
        inp5: document.getElementById('inp5').value,
      }
      console.log(myObject);
    }
</script>
```